# Картинка в стриггрид заполнение

Tags: delphi, gridview, строки

скрин =

[image: Imgur]

как убрать пробелы?

```
tringgrid3.Canvas.Brush.Color:=clGreen;
stringgrid3.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);

StringGrid3.ColWidths[1]:=Image1.Picture.Width;
StringGrid3.RowHeights[1]:=Image1.Picture.Height;
StringGrid3.Canvas.StretchDraw(Rect, Image1.Picture.Graphic);
```

Comment: Почему начинающие дельфисты так любят насиловать StringGrid? Почему бы не выводить ваш морской бой в Image или на форму? Ведь гораздо удобнее.

Comment: тем более, что есть drawgrid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выделяете stringgrid, в инспекторе объектов находите свойство Options, кликаете по плюсику (или стрелке).В выпавшем списке опций находите goVertLine и goHorzLine и выставляете в false.

Если нужно кодом, тогда так

```
StringGrid1.Options:=StringGrid1.Options-[goVertLine, goHorzLine];
```